# Error 500 con wamp

Tags: php, wamp, yii

Como solucionar el error 500 que da el wamp cuando intentas acceder a un servicio.

Este es el error que me muestra el postman

> {"code":500,"mensaje":"CDbConnection failed to open the DB
>   connection.","error":true}

Comment: Para entender mejor la pregunta pon el código del servicio que estas probando

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías poner algo mas de la configuración del wamp porque asi como aparece el post no das ninguna otra pista, revisa que el servicio de base de datos ese corriendo es lo único que por el momento se me ocurre